# MEGASync in Nemo shows error: (nemo:70308): WARNING ** connect() failed

Tags: crash, connection, nemo, mega

When I start Nemo with the debug postfix (`nemo --debug`) and [MEGASync](https://mega.nz/sync) is not started & connected, I get the error on the command line:

```
** (nemo:70308): WARNING **: 14:01:02.206: connect() failed
```

And also:

```
** (nemo:70308): WARNING **: 14:21:07.205: connect() failed
** (nemo:70308): DEBUG: 14:21:07.221: mega_ext_get_file_items: 0
** (nemo:70308): DEBUG: 14:21:07.474: mega_ext_get_file_items: 0
** (nemo:70308): DEBUG: 14:21:07.681: mega_ext_get_file_items: 0
** (nemo:70308): DEBUG: 14:21:07.908: mega_ext_get_file_items: 0
** (nemo:70308): DEBUG: 14:21:08.158: mega_ext_get_file_items: 0
```

When I start MEGASync the warning disappears. As I have random crashes of Nemo on my Ubuntu 20.04, I wonder whether there is a connection and how I can stop these warnings. I have not found an option in the preferences of MEGASync to stop the MEGASync Nemo extension asking to check the connection every second. Possibly this warning is benign and I just leave it.

Any tips or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer. Nemo still crashes randomly especially when I have opened several tabs with folders containing pictures. This happened even while the MEGAsync Nemo extension did not work for a while.
It works again and I still get the errors.

The DEBUG-warning `** (nemo:70308): DEBUG: 14:21:07.681: mega_ext_get_file_items: 0` seems to **not** indicate a **problem** as another user had [the same and the MEGASync extension was working well](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1756045).

The warning `** (nemo:95094): WARNING **: 16:45:54.719: connect() failed`
is probably related to the fact that the **MEGAsync app** is **off** and the **connection** to the MEGA server is **not** found by the MEGAsync Nemo extension.