# Journal entries are filled with nemo: connect() failed

Tags: nemo, 22.10, systemd-journald, ubuntu-unity

My `journalctl` entries are filled with `nemo[50830]: connect() failed`.

```
$ journalctl -r
Nov 09 16:38:45 iMac nemo[50830]: connect() failed
Nov 09 16:38:45 iMac nemo-desktop[2887]: connect() failed
Nov 09 16:38:44 iMac nemo-desktop[2887]: connect() failed
Nov 09 16:38:44 iMac nemo[50830]: connect() failed
Nov 09 16:38:43 iMac nemo-desktop[2887]: connect() failed
Nov 09 16:38:43 iMac nemo[50830]: connect() failed
```

I did not notice any bug, but I wonder why nemo is complaining twice every second.

I am using Ubuntu Unity 22.10.

Note: These entries are present since the date of system installation.

Comment: The OP says "I did not notice any bug" so why does the reason for closing say Bug reports? 22.10 is not a development version.

Comment: I am voting to close this as duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273524/megasync-in-nemo-shows-error-nemo70308-warning-connect-failed. MegaSync not running was the issue.

Comment: There seems to be a discussion in "Downboat" as to whether you actually intended to vote to close this question or if the Bot did it.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I closed it because the other question proposes a workaround. But, thanks for asking 

Answer (score 1):

Could be because of multiple tabs open, nemo extensions that crash.
See the below for more details.
[MEGASync in Nemo shows error: (nemo:70308): WARNING ** connect() failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273524/megasync-in-nemo-shows-error-nemo70308-warning-connect-failed)